# Fixing blurred lines that are drawn by DrawingBrush

Tags: wpf, xaml

This is my drawing brush:

```
<DrawingBrush x:Key="GridBrush" TileMode="Tile"
Viewport="0,0,60,30" ViewportUnits="Absolute"
Viewbox="0,0,60,30" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing>
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                <GeometryGroup>
                    <LineGeometry EndPoint="0,30"/>
                    <LineGeometry EndPoint="60,0"/>
                </GeometryGroup>
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                <Pen Brush="DarkGray" Thickness="1" DashCap="Flat" >
                    <Pen.DashStyle>
                        <DashStyle Dashes="2,2"/>
                    </Pen.DashStyle>
                </Pen>
            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
        </GeometryDrawing>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
```

This is where I use it:

```
<Border Width="721" Background="{StaticResource GridBrush}"  UseLayoutRounding="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" >
```

And the effects is:

[image: blurred]
[image: blurredZoomed]

Basically the middle line is "okish" the other two are wider then they should. I tried using UseLayoutRounding, SnapsToDevicePixels but with or without those options nothing changes. I ran out of ideas by now :/

Comment: maybe your windows UI is scaled more that 100%?

Comment: Try adding empty `RenderTransform` element to your `DrawingBrush`

Comment: Negate the aliasing; `RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"`